# OnItemClickListener, не получается ловить нажатие на элемент списка ListView

Tags: android, listview

Пишу простенькое приложение по сбору цен на разные товары. Сейчас пытаюсь оптимизировать часть кода, который работает со списком.
Когда разметка элемента списка была из 2-3 элементов проблем не возникало, но когда я сделал сложную разметку, элементы списка не реагируют на мое нажатие. Но лонгКлик на `EditText` ловится, вообще не пойму что не так...

Элемент списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/priceGoodsName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:editable="false" android:textSize="10dp">
    </EditText>
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/priceDay"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/priceFPrice"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:textSize="20dp" android:editable="false"/>
            <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/priceBMiss"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Список айтемов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="bottom">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/bAdded"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/bDeleted"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

class MyActivity:

```
package com.example.myapp;
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
private static Cursor mNotesCursor;
private static DBworker mDbHelper;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;

private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

private Button bAdd;
private Button bDel;
private ListView lv;

public final int lMainPage = R.layout.firstpage;
public final int lItemText = MyCustomAdapter.lITEM_TEXT;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(lMainPage);
    mDbHelper = new DBworker(this).open();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    fillData();

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            onListItemClick((ListView) adapterView, view, i, l);
        }
    });

    bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdded);
    bDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDeleted);
}

private void fillData() {
    mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);
    CursorAdapter notes = new MyCustomAdapter(this, mNotesCursor);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            onSet();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

private void onSet() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Item.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Item.class);
    i.putExtra(DBworker.KEY_ID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
```

Адаптер

```
package com.example.myapp;
public class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private Cursor cursor;
private Context context;

//Разметка
public static int lLIST_ITEM = R.layout.reg_line;
public static int lITEM_TEXT = R.id.priceDay;
public static String[] str = {DBworker.KEY_NAME};
public static int[] init = {lITEM_TEXT};


public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, lLIST_ITEM, cursor, str, init);
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Toast.makeText(this.context, "проверка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// Класс для сохранения во внешний класс и для ограничения доступа
private static class ViewHolder {
    public long rowid;
    public EditText name;
    public EditText fPrice;
    public ToggleButton bMiss;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(lLIST_ITEM, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.fPrice = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceFPrice);
        holder.name = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceGoodsName);
        holder.bMiss = (ToggleButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceBMiss);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    cursor.moveToPosition(pos);

    holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBworker.KEY_NAME)));//NAME
       holder.fPrice.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBworker.KEY_ID)));//FACT_NAME

    holder.rowid = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID_GOODS"));
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Воркер для работы с базой

```
package com.example.myapp;
public class DBworker {
public static final String DB_NAME = "myDB";
public static final String TABLE = "myDB";
public static final String KEY_ID = "ID_GOODS";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "NAME";
public static final String KEY_PULL = "NOTE";
public static final String KEY_CARDS = "FACT_NAME";
private final Context mCtx;

static ContentValues cvDataB;
public SQLiteDatabase db;
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final String query = "create table " + TABLE + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_NAME + " text, "
            + KEY_PULL + " text, "
            + KEY_CARDS + " text"
            + ");";

    private final String query1 = "CREATE TABLE myDB (ID_GOODS  INT,DB_GOODS    INT,ID_CITY INT,ID_ORG  INT,DB_ORG  INT,ID_CIPC INT,FIRST_ID    INT," +
            "NAME   TEXT,NOTE   TEXT,EVAL_EXPR  TEXT,IS_IMP INT,FACT_SIZE   REAL,FACT_UNIT  INT,FACT_NAME   TEXT,IS_ADD INT,IS_CHANGE   INT," +
            "IS_DEL INT,IS_ACTIVE   INT,DATE_FROM   NUM,DATE_TO NUM,DATE_CORR   NUM,REC_HASH    TEXT)";

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(query1);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DBworker(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}


public long onSetTemp(String name, String pull) {
    cvDataB = new ContentValues();
    cvDataB.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cvDataB.put(KEY_PULL, pull);
    return db.insert(TABLE, null, cvDataB);
}

public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {
    return db.delete(TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {
    //return db.query("dbTemp", new String[] {"pName", "pPull", "pCardPull"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    return db.rawQuery("select " + KEY_ID + " as _id, * from " + TABLE, null);
}

public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    //Cursor mCursor =db.query(true, DB_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME}, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null,null, null, null, null);
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select " + KEY_ID + " as _id, * from " + TABLE + " where " + KEY_ID + " = " + rowId + " ", null);
    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        byte[] bytes = mCursor.getBlob(0);
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, title);
    args.put(KEY_PULL, body);

    return db.update(TABLE, args, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public DBworker open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

}
```

Comment: @pavlofff
Делаю так:  `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() `
потом перегружаю  `onListItemClick`

Comment: @pavlofff Сейчас упростил файлы разметки и "почистил" код для лучшей читаемости... Может сейчас станет понятней...
Мой способ реализации практически не отличается от предложенных в ваших примерах, в моем понимании, может не уловили какую-то тонкость... еще не в совершенстве воспринимаю английский текст

Comment: и еще видимо вы перепутали разметки в вопросе. Та, которая вверху - разметка айтема, а ниже - активити, у вас подписано наоборот. И по какому элементу из разметки айтема вам нужно отработать клик? или по всему айтему ?

Comment: @pavlofff. Спасибо поправил. 
Вот я подключаю слушатель к `ListVew`

        `lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`

мне нужно ловить нажатие именно на элемент, т.к. внутри элемента только информационная нагрузка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слишком много кликабелных элементов внутри элемента списка. Попробуй разобраться с ними. Или установить `View.OnClickListener` на корневой лайоут элемента списка.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Попытался выставить на всех элементах разметки 'false'(поля, слои). Даже в промежуточных запусках была реакция на нажатие элемента(приводила к крашу), дабы выделить место "краша" упростил разметку. После упрощения "реакция" на нажатие пропала, откатывал изменения и по шагово пробовал упрощать и запускать, но реакции на нажатие не повторилось(

Уточните - `Или установить View.OnClickListener на корневой лайоут элемента списка.`

Comment: Пересоздав полностью разметку и более внимательно прошустрив настройки каждой, я смог решить проблему. Проблема была в банальной не аккуратности при создании разметок...

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно отработать клик по всему айтему, то все достаточно просто:

Это нужно **УДАЛИТЬ**:

```
private ListView lv;

...

lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

...

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        onListItemClick((ListView) adapterView, view, i, l);
    }
});
```

У вас повешано два слушателя на один список, поэтому тот, что выше надо удалить, а `onListItemClick()` оставить, так как он имплементируется `ListActivity` / Для `ListActivity` нет необходимости отдельно вешать слушатель и искать `ListView` в разметке - все это уже встроено в данную активити по дефолту.

При этом клик по айтему будет отрабатываться только там, где нет элементов в айтеме, реагирующих на клик, в вашем случае `EditText` и `ToggleButton` - они будут перехватывать фокус, естественно.

Comment: Я понял, элементам, которые могут "слушать" события, нужно проставить `android:focusable="false"`, и сделать согласно вами вышеизложенному.

Т.к. у меня была куча разных фокусов, конкретный клик на итем не улавливался, спасибо. Сейчас усложню разметку и попробую с ней.